# Keras data generator "Error when checking input: expected input_8 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape ()"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using data generator in Keras to train a model with a large dataset. But I am getting the error `Error when checking input: expected input_8 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape ()` ever time on the last batch of the first epoch. But I checked my dataset file, it doesn't have an empty array, so how did empty array come? I even tried printing the array as they were generated and few of them were shown empty. Here is my code for the data generator:

```
class data_generator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self,data_file,type_data,batch_size,shuffle=True):
        self.data_file = data_file
        self.type_data = type_data

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
      if self.type_data == "train":
        self.indices = np.arange(3450000)
      else:
        self.indices = np.arange(345000)
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indices)

    def __data__generation(self,indices):

        return X,Y        

    def __len__(self):
      if self.type_data == "train":
        return int(np.ceil(10000 / float(self.batch_size)))
      else:
        return int(np.ceil(1000 / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        #print(self.indices[(index)*self.batch_size], self.indices[(index+1)*self.batch_size])
        X = np.array(HDF5Matrix(self.data_file, self.type_data + "_X", start = self.indices[index*self.batch_size], end = self.indices[(index+1)*self.batch_size]))
        Y = np.array(HDF5Matrix(self.data_file, self.type_data + "_Y", start = self.indices[index*self.batch_size], end = self.indices[(index+1)*self.batch_size]))
        #print(X.shape, Y.shape)
        return X,Y
```

And here is my code for starting the fit generator:

```
train_generator = data_generator("drive/My Drive/Dataset/dataset.h5", "train", 20)
eval_generator = data_generator("drive/My Drive/Dataset/dataset.h5", "eval", 20)
model = create_model()
history = model.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,epochs = 100,validation_data=eval_generator,use_multiprocessing=False)
```

How do I solve this issue? Also is there any alternative for data generator for training on large datasets? The data generator is very buggy and gives lots of error.

Comment: Test your data generators. Before passing it to ```fit_generator``` make sure it can run for a full iteration while returning the expect results. Specifically test ```train_generator[len(generator) - 1]```. You code shows that the eval generator is shuffled but not the train... which is the inverse of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code had few mistakes. I changed it and now it is working, but still, don't know why exactly that error occurred. Here is the new code:

```
class data_generator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self,data_file,type_data,batch_size,shuffle=True):
        self.data_file = data_file
        self.type_data = type_data

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
      if self.type_data == "train":
        self.indices = np.arange(3450000)
      else:
        self.indices = np.arange(345000)
      if self.shuffle:
         np.random.shuffle(self.indices)

    def __data__generation(self,indices):
      X = []
      Y = []
      for index in indices:
        X.append(np.array(HDF5Matrix(self.data_file, self.type_data + "_X", start = index, end = index + 1)[0]))
        Y.append(np.array(HDF5Matrix(self.data_file, self.type_data + "_Y", start = index, end = index + 1)[0]))
      X = np.array(X)
      Y = np.array(Y)
      return X,Y        

    def __len__(self):
      if self.type_data == "train":
        return int(np.ceil(3450000 / float(self.batch_size)))
      else:
        return int(np.ceil(345000 / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        indices = self.indices[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        X, Y = self.__data__generation(indices)
        #print(X.shape, Y.shape, index)
        return X,Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras needs while true (infinite loop) to avoid StopIteration. But in a plain generator, after correct steps_per_epoch (sample_size//batch_size), the shape would be zero.